# Let's speed that file sentence searching program

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

#### Intro:

I've written a small piece of Python program which is looking for a given sentence in multiple sub directories of a given path.

I'm looking for improvements regarding the speed of my script.

---

#### Code:

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join


def get_magik_files(base_path):
    """
    Yields each path from all the base_path subdirectories

    :param base_path: this is the base path from where we'll start looking after .magik files
    :return: yield full path of a .magik file
    """
    for dirpath, _, filenames in walk(base_path):
        for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".magik")]:
            yield join(dirpath, filename)


def search_sentence_in_file(base_path, sentence):
    """
    Prints each file path, line and line content where sentence was found

    :param base_path: this is the base path from where we'll start looking after .magik files
    :param sentence: the sentence we're looking up for
    :return: print the file path, line number and line content where sentence was found
    """
    for each_magik_file in get_magik_files(base_path):
        with open(each_magik_file) as magik_file:
            for line_number, line in enumerate(magik_file):
                if sentence in line:
                    print('[# FILE PATH    #] {} ...\n'
                          '[# LINE NUMBER  #] At line  {}\n'
                          '[# LINE CONTENT #] Content: {}'.format(each_magik_file, line_number, line.strip()))
                    print('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------')


def main():
    basepath = r'some_path'
    sentence_to_search = 'some sentence'

    search_sentence_in_file(basepath, sentence_to_search)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

#### Miscellaneous:

As you may already figured out, the reason for my program being so slow resides in `search_sentence_in_file(base_path, sentence)` where I need to open each file, read it line by line and look for a specific sentence.

I know I could use a *logging library* instead of `print`ing the results to see who matched what, but that wouldn't serve the purposes of the program. So I'm not looking for that (I'm building this to have a fast way of looking for certain classes / methods / slots definitions in multiple `.magik` files in a fast manner. Opening a log file won't satisfy me).

For whoever is interested in the Magik language, and as a bonus of taking your time to take a look at this question, [here's a small introduction to Magik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magik_(programming_language)).

---

**To sum up:**

- is there any way of improving the speed of my program ?
- do you have other suggestions regarding the way I'm searching a sentence ?

*PS: I'm looking for answers which aims a Windows distro*.

Any other improvements are welcomed !

Comment: Fulltext search in files is something that is inherently slow. Indexing is what mitigates that when you search in Windows OS.

Comment: Just curious: Why isn't a combination of `find` and `grep`, or only the letter with the `-R` flag being used?  I hear grep has significant efforts to search efficiently and seems to be capable of what you want, and that is searching for text in a file or multiple files.  I tend to get these tools available on all OSes.

Comment: @Pysis because this script is Windows aimed and I don't want to install any third party (like grep) or to call a Windows command to achieve what I can achieve with Python by itself :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yay, PEP 8

72 characters for docstrings, 79 for the code. The rest seems fine.

## Separation of concerns

`search_sentence_in_file` should search, and return its results. Not `print`, it is the duty of the caller.

I feel it is also wrongly named as it search a sentence in several files. So at least add the missing `s` at the end of the name. And to make it even more reusable, why not pass an iterable of filepath (like the `get_magic_files` generator)?

## Genericity

Besides `search_sentence_in_file` accepting an iterable, you could make `get_magik_files` more generic by passing the required extension as a parameter. This will let you extend your script to allow search in various kind of files.

## First rewrite

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join, splitext


def get_files(base_path, extension=None):
    """
    Yields each path from all the base_path subdirectories

    :param base_path: this is the base path from where the
                      function start looking for relevant files
    :param extension: filter files using provided extension.
                      If None, no filter is applied.
    :return: yield full path of a requested file
    """
    if extension is None:
        def filter_files(filenames):
            yield from filenames
    else:
        def filter_files(filenames):
            for filename in filenames:
                if splitext(filename)[1] == extension:
                    yield filename

    for dirpath, _, filenames in walk(base_path):
        for filename in filter_files(filenames):
            yield join(dirpath, filename)


def search_sentence_in_files(files, sentence):
    """
    Yield each file path, line and line content where
    sentence was found.

    :param files: iterable of files to search the sentence into
    :param sentence: the sentence we're looking up for
    :return: yield the file path, line number and line
             content where sentence was found
    """
    for filepath in files:
        with open(filepath) as fp:
            for line_number, line in enumerate(fp):
                if sentence in line:
                    yield filepath, line_number, line.strip()


def main():
    basepath = r'some_path'
    sentence_to_search = 'some sentence'

    files = get_files(basepath, 'magik')
    results = search_sentence_in_files(files, sentence_to_search)
    for filepath, line, content in results:
        print('[# FILE PATH    #]', filepath, '...')
        print('[# LINE NUMBER  #] At line', line)
        print('[# LINE CONTENT #] Content:', content)
        print('-'*80)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Reusability

Your script make it hard to reuse for other purposes: different sentences, different kind of files. Better to add a CLI using `argparse`. Provide sensible default for your current usage but allows for customization at will.

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join, splitext
import argparse


def get_files(base_path, extension=None):
    """
    Yields each path from all the base_path subdirectories

    :param base_path: this is the base path from where the
                      function start looking for relevant files
    :param extension: filter files using provided extension.
                      If None, no filter is applied.
    :return: yield full path of a requested file
    """
    if extension is None:
        def filter_files(filenames):
            yield from filenames
    else:
        def filter_files(filenames):
            for filename in filenames:
                if splitext(filename)[1] == extension:
                    yield filename

    for dirpath, _, filenames in walk(base_path):
        for filename in filter_files(filenames):
            yield join(dirpath, filename)


def search_sentence_in_files(files, sentence):
    """
    Yield each file path, line and line content where
    sentence was found.

    :param files: iterable of files to search the sentence into
    :param sentence: the sentence we're looking up for
    :return: yield the file path, line number and line
             content where sentence was found
    """
    for filepath in files:
        with open(filepath) as fp:
            for line_number, line in enumerate(fp):
                if sentence in line:
                    yield filepath, line_number, line.strip()


def main(files, sentence):
    results = search_sentence_in_files(files, sentence)
    for filepath, line, content in results:
        print('[# FILE PATH    #]', filepath, '...')
        print('[# LINE NUMBER  #] At line', line)
        print('[# LINE CONTENT #] Content:', content)
        print('-'*80)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Search text in files')
    parser.add_argument('sentence')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--basepath',
                        help='folder in wich files will be examinated',
                        default=r'some folder')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--extension',
                        help='extension of files to examine',
                        default='magik')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    files = get_files(args.basepath, args.extension)
    main(files, args.sentence)
```

You can also allows for other improvements such as the `sentence` being a regular expression.

Answer (score 10):

This:

```
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".magik")]:
        yield join(dirpath, filename)
```

could be rewritten in a clearer and more efficient way (no list creation):

```
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".magik"):
            yield join(dirpath, filename)
```